# define a function (method) from a class

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```cs
SendNotificationClass sendNotifClass = new sendNotificationClass();
```

but I want to define the function from it called "SendNotification"

so instead of

```
SendNotificationClass sendNotifClass = new sendNotificationClass();
SendNotifClass.SendNotification();
```

i want  to do it like this:

```
var sendNotif = new SendNotificationClass().SendNotification;
sendNotif(...)
```

how?

Comment: In your particular case (assuming that the return type of the method is `void`), it would be `Action sendNotif = new sendNotificationClass().SendNotification;`. If the method have a return type (say, `int`), then you should use `Func<int> sendNotif = ...`.

Comment: create a delegate that has a matching signature with SenNotification method. Then invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [*anonymous delegate*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/anonymous-functions) by changing your syntax slightly:

```
var sendNotif = () => (new sendNotificationClass()).SendNotification();
sendNotif()
```

If `sendNotif` requires parameters (as implied by your use of an ellipsis), then you just need to add them to the delegate definition:

```
var sendNotif = (x, y, Z) => (new sendNotificationClass()).SendNotification(x, y, z);
sendNotif(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of different options. Just to name of few:

#### void SendNotification()

```cs
public delegate void NotifDelegate();

...
var sendNotifClass = new SendNotificationClass();
NotifDelegate sendNotif1 = new NotifDelegate(sendNotifClass.SendNotification);
NotifDelegate sendNotif2 = sendNotifClass.SendNotification;

Action sendNotif3 = delegate { sendNotifClass.SendNotification(); };
Action sendNotif4 =  () => sendNotifClass.SendNotification();
Action sendNotif5 = sendNotifClass.SendNotification;
```

Usage

```cs
sendNotif1.Invoke(); //Either
sendNotif1(); //Or
...
sendNotif5.Invoke(); //Either
sendNotif5(); //Or
```

#### bool SendNotification(string email)

```cs
public delegate bool NotifWithParamDelegate(string param1);
...

NotifWithParamDelegate notifWithParam1 = new NotifWithParamDelegate(sendNotifClass.SendNotification);
NotifWithParamDelegate notifWithParam2 = sendNotifClass.SendNotification;

Func<string, bool> notifWithParam3 = delegate (string email) { return sendNotifClass.SendNotification(email); };
Func<string, bool> notifWithParam4 = email => sendNotifClass.SendNotification(email);
Func<string, bool> notifWithParam5 = sendNotifClass.SendNotification;
```

Usage

```cs
bool isSuccess = notifWithParam1.Invoke("a@b.c"); //Either
bool isSuccess = notifWithParam1("a@b.c"); //Or
...
bool isSuccess = notifWithParam5.Invoke("a@b.c"); //Either
bool isSuccess = notifWithParam5("a@b.c"); //Or
```